# Connecting oracle 10 G through python 2.4

Tags: python

Hi I want to connect to oracle through python .Python is installed in  my window machine whose version is (2.4) . Oracle 11G is install in UNIX box . I want to know in which machine and which folder i need to install "cx_Oracle" DB API , and in which machine(UNIX or oracle) i need to set ORACLE_HOME path.Please let me know the whole step .

Please get back to me as it is too much essential for me.

Answer (score 0):

cx_Oracle is a python module, it should be install to python site-packages folder. But looks they don't support python2.4 on Windows. http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/.

cx_Oracle requires an Oracle [client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). You need to configure Oracle client path to locate sqlplus binary.

One approach is using sqlplus to verify wehther the connection works as expect. Then use cx_Oracle to connect.